# Win32 console-only app, prevent "missing dll" dialog box

Tags: c, visual-studio-2010, winapi, console-application

I have built a VS2010 console app. When I run this app on a machine without the necessary dlls a dialog box pops up with the message "The program can't start because MSVCR100.dll is missing from your computer". That's fair enough.

The problem is that the program hangs until someone clicks OK.

This program is a part of a complicated automated build setup, so I really need it to terminate with an error code instead.

Are there any solutions (e.g. VS2010 project setup options) I can apply to fix this?

Comment: You could try calling [SetErrorMode](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/desktop/ms680621%28v=vs.85%29.aspx) before launching the app (assuming you control the launching process), though I don't know if it applies to the DLL-not-found message box.

Comment: arx is right. I just encountered the same issue and SetErrorMode(SEM_FAILCRITICALERRORS) prevents the modal error message, instead the CreateProcess call succeeds but the process returns STATUS_DLL_NOT_FOUND as an exit code

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can change your project to static link the CRT rather than dynamic link it (set the run-time library option to **Multi-threaded** rather than **Multi-threaded DLL**).

[image]

Comment: This will solve the problem, I agree. But to satisfy my curiosity I would really like to know if it is possible to "redirect" the dialog box to the console. It seems wrong that a console app is forced to use a GUI in some circumstances.

Comment: I don't think there's a way to redirect the dialog box (not one I've ever come across anyway). The only other option I can think of is to try [delay loading](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/151kt790.aspx) the DLLs in question, with an exception handler that catches the failure and aborts the process with a message to the console. I don't know if that will work for the CRT DLLs however.

Comment: @Jakob In general, you could manually load DLLs via `LoadLibrary` and `GetProcAddress`, and then you're free to handle failure however you want.  But for the CRT DLLs, I think static linking is the way to go.